# Formatting Long value to Date String?

Tags: android, date, string-formatting, android-date

I am working on an application in which I have to convert a long value to a Date string and display. To achieve the purpose I am using following function, but it is returning me the date from `70's and 80's` obviously not appropriate. I am using the following finction:

```
public static String convertDateFromLongToCompleteString(long date) {
    Date d = new Date(date * 1000);
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
    String formattedDateFromLong = dateformat.format(d);
    return formattedDateFromLong;
}
```

The long value is just simply `System.currentTimeMillis()` and when I have to show it to the user, I have to format that for which I am using above function. I have checked system and device dates, their zones and time, everything is just fine. Please update that why is this issue appearing and how can I get the exact date. Thanks!

**Edit**

I have also tried withoout multiplication with 1000, it gives me time and date from 1970.

Comment: No need to do `(date * 1000)` when your are calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` if no other logic is required.

Comment: @Egor it gives me date and time of 1970 if i don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

If your `long date` is simply `System.currentTimeMillis()`, then multiplication with `1000` is not required.

`Date d = new Date(date);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `Date d = new Date(date * 1000);` with `Date d = new Date(date);`

Comment: The way you're using it will give you a time like the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 GMT. * 1000 - which is around END of February year 44 970 I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using the above method only with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, you can call `Date` constructor without any parameters, it will give you the `Date` object that refers to the current date and time. This will be an easier way to solve your problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the time, save its value in DB, when I have to show it to user then I format it.

Comment: @UsamaSarwar, Are you sure that after you store the value in DB and then get it back it's the same value? Maybe that's the problem? Cause I don't really believe that System.currentTimeMillis() is giving you 1970, if of course you're not in 1970 :)

Comment: ye..I save this value in a table and then retrieve that saved value.

Comment: @UsamaSarwar, And the value is still wrong? There's a mistake in your code somewhere and there are not enough details for me to help you find it.